# Displaying Width of Tables on Page with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, width, each

Sometimes I let the easiest 101 type questions get me!  Well, time for the latest chapter.
Lets say I have a html page with one or more tables.  Using jQuery I want to display the width of each table found.

Here's the my simple / basic table html -

```
 <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 500px;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col"></th>
                    <th scope="col"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p>
        </p>
        <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 250px;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p>
        </p>
        <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 500px;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Here's the jQuery I'm using -

```
    <script>
   $(document).on("pageshow", function () {          
          $("table:visible").each(function () {
        alert($(this).width);
    });
   });
   </script>
```

I'm using pageshow being this will be part of a jquery mobile site but it easily could be the standard jquery document.ready.

I do indeed get the alert prompt three times but I am not getting width of the current table (this).  I'm getting some long message like this -

```
function (i,o){var a=arguments.length&&(r||"boolean"!=typeof i),s=r||(i===!0||o===!0?"margin":"border");return b.access(this,function(n,r,i){var o;return b.isWindow(n)?n.document.documentElement["client"+e]:9===n.nodeType?(o=n.documentElement,Math.max(n.body["scroll"+e],o["scroll"+e],n.body["offset"+e],o["offset"+e],o["client"+e])):i===t?b.css(n,r,s):b.style(n,r,i,s)},n,a?i:t,a,null)}
```

So what obvious thing am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Try using `$(this).width()` instead of `$(this).width`

Comment: you missed bracket $(this).width();

Comment: Ha haha  I just love to laugh at myself sometimes. Thank you. I guess I let the width property vs the width function confuse me.

Comment: Getting the screen width in javascript uses the syntax screen.width without the brackets.  Not sure why a difference and I think this is what confused me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code

```
$(document).on("pageshow", function () {          
    $("table:visible").each(function () {
        alert($(this).width());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the brackets after width() gave me the functionality I was looking for.

Comment: Even if it came after the comment from Pedro?

Comment: I'm all about rules and regulations.   Per article 9.323 sub-paragraph 23.3 niner , rule 29.23 repeating 3 I have proceeded to give zessx the credit.  Thanks again for all your help.   :-)